# how to use gsutil rsync. login and download bucket contents to a local directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, gsutil, google-bucket

I have the following questions.

I got access to a cloud bucket to my email id. Now I want to download the whole bucket folder into a local directory on ubuntu. I installed gsutil from pip.

1. Is the command correct?

> `gsutil rsync gs://bucket_name .`

2. the command seems generic how do I give my gmail credentials to it? The file is 1TB of size and I am allowed to download only once so I want to get the command right.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, it'd be great if you could accept it :) Please let me know if it doesn't or you have any other questions!

Answer (score 3):

1. The command is correct if you want your current directory to mirror the contents of the bucket (including deleting any files on the right not found on the left). If you merely want to copy, you might want `cp -r` instead.
2. [Here are the current docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#creds-gsutil) on how to authenticate when running a standalone gsutil. It looks like you just need to run `gsutil config`.